# What is MySQL Collation, how to use it in practice?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I want to make a search engine in some weird languages in 4 languages:

English
Swedish
Hebrew
Arabic

How would I set the collations in MySQL ?

Comment: I've set it to utf8 and it works like a charm for multilingual dbs.

Comment: Which languages? And haven't you had problems with sorting and the like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collation determines how MySQL compares strings.

A list of all character sets and collations can be found with:

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET;
SHOW COLLATION;
```

To change the collation for a table use:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html

Answer (score 4):

A collation defines:

- The character set used to store the characters (UTF8, ISO8859, etc.)
- The sorting and presentation rules

If you want to have different languages (where they cannot be sanely represented in the same collation, as you mention) you can have [columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html) with different collations.

Of course you can set collation [at database and table levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html) too, and even set collation to a [string literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-literal.html).

If you can find a single collation that handles all the languages you're interested in, that's best.