# What is the collation of a MySQL 4.0.20 database/table/column/string?

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, collation

I want to find out which collation the mySQL database has. phpMyAdmin 2.8.0.3 doesn't show me that. Is there a command like mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854866/what-is-mysql-collation-how-to-use-it-in-practice)? I would need it for the database, table, column and perhaps the string literal.

Comment: I believe you should see this in `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Or just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`.

Answer (score 1):

[SHOW COLLATION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-collation.html) appeared in mysql 4.1, actually, there wasn't much information about collations and character sets in 4.0. See the [release notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/news-4-1-0.html) for 4.1.0. My guess is that you can't get this information. I also think you can assume it's latin-1 as that was the default in 4.0.

Comment: It would be enough if I could use a command like `SHOW CHARACTER SET;` or `SHOW COLLATION;` but they don't work here: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET' at line 1`.

Comment: I just noticed that `SHOW COLLATION` is available since 4.1

Comment: These commands list the available character sets and collations which don't seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Latin-1 seem likely. But I have also UTF-8 data in one of the tables. When querying I get UTF-8 back, but I quite don't know why. Thats the reason why was asking this question. So the default character set would also be latin-1?

Comment: By default, yes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-conversion.html. Also interesting read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-upgrading.html

Comment: Do you know a way how to find out the current collation/charset pair is? In the case it is not default?

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` should include the character set and collation for the table.

To get the default for the database, try this:

```
show variables like 'character_set_database';
show variables like 'collation_database';
```

Not sure if these are available in your MySQL version however.

Comment: I tried your first command and I see the same when exporting the database. There is nothing about the collation. I Only get `TYPE=MyISAM`. I I try the last both commands I see nothing but the command was executed successfully. Isn't there a way to find this out?

Comment: There probably is, but I'm not very familiar with such an old MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

On my version 4.0.15 DB, I have been able to do:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%char%";
```

And get:

[image: Show Variables Charset Result]